# Хороший вопрос - залог хорошего ответа

Tags: поддержка, faq, вопросы

Stack Overflow на русском – это сайт вопросов и ответов. Поэтому важно уделить особое внимание тому, как правильно задавать вопросы, чтобы на них давались хорошие качественные ответы. Ниже мы дадим ряд советов (основанных на заметке), как повысить качество вопросов.

1. **Сделайте все возможное сами**. Перед тем, как задать вопрос, попробуйте исследовать предметную область и найти ответ на вопрос. Если решение не удалось найти, приведите краткую сводку попыток решить проблему. Тем самым участники форума будут избавлены от необходимости искать информацию по теме и получат возможность сосредоточиться на главном - ответе на ваш вопрос.
2. **Формулируйте вопрос подробно, ясно и точно**. На туманный расплывчатый вопрос, который с трудом можно понять с третьего прочтения, вряд ли будет дан подробный, ясный и точный ответ. Чем неопределеннее вопрос, тем неопределеннее ответ. Поэтому чтобы получить определенный, а следовательно полезный ответ, нужно и излагать его определенно.
3. **Будьте лаконичны**. Удалите ненужную специфику из вопроса. Оставьте самое существенное. Таким образом будут достигнуты две цели: участникам сообщества, отвечающим на вопрос, не придется тратить свое время на чтение ненужного и выделение нужного; вопрос в «чистом виде» превратиться в учебный пример, полезный многим программистам и системным администраторам, нашедшим вопрос и ответы к нему через поиск.
4. **Воспринимайте ответы творчески**. Возможно, ответы, полученные на вопрос, не будут однозначно отвечать на него. В этом случае всегда можно уточнить их через комментарии и попробовать доосмыслить.
5. **Форматируйте текст изящно**. Stack Overflow на русском использует язык разметки [Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), который позволяет просто и непринужденно выделять заголовки и абзацы, оформлять списки и указывать ссылки. Чтобы добавить исходный код программы и увидеть его в отформатированном виде с подсветкой синтаксиса, просто предварите его четырьмя пробелами.

Comment: Уверены, что пункт 1 должен быть именно таким? Если достаточно формально ему следовать, то вообще-то получается безрадостная картина. /  Смотрите, если я сделал **все возможное** сам, то скорее всего найду решение (в противном случае, вероятность ответа здесь крайне мала). Как следствие (если я не чистый филантроп), моя заинтересованность в сайте падает (поскольку быстро спрашивать (как следует из п.1) нельзя). И в конце   логического развития такой цепочки рассуждений -- *зачем тогда мне вообще отвечать на чужие  вопросы?* / Т.е. п. 1 надо бы сформулиовать как-то помягче...

Comment: @avp Модель Stack Overflow подразумевает прикладные вопросы. Первый пункт лишь подчеркивает эту особенность. Таким образом, если вопрос прикладной, контекст будет обязательно. По сути, мы воспроизводим случай из реальной жизни, когда инженер подходит к коллеге за советом по проекту. Согласитесь, было бы не очень хорошо, если бы к нам подходило пол отдела поговорить за жизнь, но с другой стороны мы всегда рады помочь коллеге конкретным советом. И, скорее всего, первый вопросом будет «Что вы сделали, что не получилось?». Если коллега не может ответить, то скорее всего он не пробовал разобраться.

Answer (score 14):

Мне кажется, вы забыли упомянуть несколько очень важных моментов:

1. Самое важное. Вопрос и ответы на него, должны быть полезны не только (и даже не столько!) автору вопроса, а и всем остальным, кто столкнется с похожей проблемой. Этот принцип, по моему мнению, ключевой вообще для всего ресурса. Без его понимания не понятно почему вопросы закрываются, как отвечать на комментарии, да и чем вообще здесь люди занимаются и почему РУСО не форум.
2. Лучший способ "качественно" задать вопрос или ответить на него, это внимательно читать комментарии и отвечать на вопросы и замечания в них, соответсвующими правками своего текста. Иными словами - без обратной связи никуда.