# Почему бы не сделать зависимость меток?

Tags: предложение

Задаю я вопрос по Visual Studio. Какие метки мне использовать? Я использовал `visual-studio` и `visual-studio-2015`

Если изучить подписчиков меток, то будет видно, что кто то подписан только на версию студии, которая у него установлена, но не подписан на саму метку `visual-studio`. А ведь возможно, ответ на мой вопрос есть у пользователей студии 2013. Это один из последних примеров.

У меня были подобные случаи и в вопросах по программированию. Не могу найти ссылку на вопрос для примера, но дело было так. Я задал вопрос и расставил метки, подписчики которых могли мне помочь. На меня сразу наехал местный бугор, типа вот эта и эта метки лишние. В ходе спора выяснилось, что логически я не прав. Но это только в том случае, если все люди подписаны на все метки, в которых они могут помочь. Некоторые подписываются только на обобщенные метки, а другие на все, кроме обобщенных. В итоге, пока мы разбирались с метками, на вопрос ответил человек, который был подписан на одну из "лишних" меток.

А так же, задавая вопрос по c# я по сути задаю его по возможностям framework, и реже по синтаксису. А значит мне могут подсказать и программисты на Visual Basic .NET.

В общем я предлагаю добавить зависимости у меток. То есть, если я подписываюсь на метку visual-studio, то меня автоматом подписывает на visual-studio-2005,2008 и тд, а я уже отписываюсь при желании от ненужных.

**UPD:**

Хорошо, если не навязывать ничего, а сделать так. Я подписываюсь на метку visual-studio, а мне при этом система говорит

> возможно, вам будут интересны и такие метки:
>   visual-studio-2008
>   visual-studio-2010

и так далее... а работать будет так. Система посмотрит, на что еще подписываются вместе с выбранной меткой и предложит самые частые связки. Как в интернет магазинах блок "с этим покупают..."

Comment: если задаете вопрос по framework, добавляйте метку [tag:net], так как в противном случае и ожидается именно решение на c# а не общее для framework

Comment: @Grundy, [tag:.net] :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага или так, когда писал не помнил есть там точка или все-таки нет, а смотреть лень было :)

Comment: @Grundy, если сравнить подписчиков метки C# и .net, будет видно, что далеко не все программисты c# отметились в .net. Это не означает, что они готовы помогать исключительно по синтаксису шарпа, это означает, что они не выбрали все возможные метки.

Comment: @iRumba, а так же возможно, им не интересны вопросы по .net

Comment: @Grundy, в этом случае они просто отпишутся от ненужной метки и все. А остальные будут подписаны именно на то, что они подразумевали, подписываясь на те или иные метки

Comment: @iRumba, либо уйдут с сайта, так как тут им навязывают что-то не спросив

Comment: @Grundy, это ж какой надо быть истеричкой, чтобы уйти из-за навязанных нескольких минут настройки профиля?

Comment: @iRumba, ну если сайту не важно мнение пользователя при выставлении тегов, мало ли что еще он по умолчанию выставит/сохранит и т.д. так что вполне нормальная реакция

Comment: @Grundy, ну так мнение всех не учесть. Как правило, любые изменения кому-то полезны, а кому-то мешают. а кому то просто лень разобраться что это за зверь новый. Я дополнил вопрос, почитайте UPD

Comment: @iRumba, да, этот вариант мне кажется более подходящим

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я знаю, эта возможность обсуждалась на заре Stack Overflow и была отклонена. Она вносит достаточно много ограничений и требований:

- Кто-то на сайте должен заниматься поддержкой связей меток;
- Какой-то разработчик должен поддерживать фичу.
- Очень многие ожидают совсем другого поведения и удивятся, что их подписали на все зависимые метки.
- Будут споры о субъективных вопросах, например приписывать [azure-cloud-switch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cloud-switch) к [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) или нет?

Так что я думаю, от такой возможности будет больше вреда, чем пользы. Тем более, вы же не себя хотите подписать, а других участников. Пусть уж они решат за себя сами и подпишутся на то, что считают нужным.

---

По другим вопросам.

> расставил метки, подписчики которых могли мне помочь

Конечно, так делать не надо. Метки обозначают не группы подписчиков, которые могут вам помочь, а тему вопроса.

> Но это только в том случае, если все люди подписаны на все метки, в которых они могут помочь.

Совсем необязательно. Кто-то (как я) использует избранные теги и фильтрует ленту новых вопросов по ним. Другие просто читают все новые вопросы. Но если участник даже и увидит вопрос, на который может дать ответ, необязательно он будет отвечать. По моим субъективным наблюдениям, лучший способ привлечь экспертов — это [хорошо оформленный](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2487/181472) вопрос по интересной проблеме.

Comment: К сожалению, хорошо оформленный вопрос - не есть гарантия того, что эксперт в предметной области этот вопрос увидит, потому что он подписан на Visual Basic, а у меня стоит метка c#. А вопрос по стандартным нетовским библиотекам. Опять же тут зависит от того, каким образом эксперт ищет вопросы.

Comment: @iRumba: на этом сайте далеко не один эксперт по .NET и, как правило, вопросы по нему не остаются без ответов. Вам нужно внимание достаточного или максимального числа экспертов?

Comment: А что касается `Тем более, вы же не себя хотите подписать, а других участников. Пусть уж они решат за себя сами и подпишутся на то, что считают нужным.` Всегда, когда добавляется новая фича, связанная с добавлением полей в базу пользователей, приходится использовать некое значение по умолчанию. И не всегда стандартное NULL приведет к ожидаемым результатам и пользователям таки придется лезть в настройки профиля и чего то менять. В данном случае то же самое. Пользователь уже в первые сутки отпишется от ненужных меток, читая ленту

Comment: @iRumba: сам факт, что человек оказался подписанным на то, на что явно не подписывался, будет воспринят очень негативно.

Comment: Конечно! Но этот негатив пройдет за 2 дня. Можно, например, при первом посещении после ввода фичи пригласить пользователя на страницу, где будет  подробно описано нововведение, а так же выведен список паразитических меток, на которые его подписали :), с указанием связей, по которым это случилось, чтобы он мог отписаться от них при желании

Comment: Речь ведь не только о подписках, но и о лимите в 5 меток на вопрос. Потом ответом распишу, если не забуду.

Comment: Я дополнил предложение. почитайте UPD

Comment: @iRumba за два дня негатив пройдет, потому что будет выплеснут на Мету и в чаты.

Answer (score 4):

Зависит одна метка от другой, или же нет - определяется содержимым конкретного вопроса. Особенно ярко это проявляется в вопросах по администрированию.

Возьмем, например, пару вопросов по метке [bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitrix) (чур-чур-чур!), которую казалось можно было бы сделать потомком [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php):

- [Почему не отображается инфоблок в редакторе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490099/17298) - человек спрашивает о том, куда кликнуть в админпанели, что бы получить нужный ему результат. Никакой связи с программированием на php тут нет - метка [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) абсолютно лишняя.
- [Отменить оплату со внутреннего счета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/475662/17298) - вопрос непосредственно о программировании компонентов для этой cms. [bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitrix) и [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) одновременно уместны.
- [не получается авторизовываться в битриксе через curl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489280/17298) - просто программирование на [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php). А вот необходимость наличия метки [bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitrix) здесь очень натянута.

Здесь довольно занятно выглядел бы типичный многоугольник балансировки статов из RPG, если расположить метки в вершинах.

[image: балансировочный многулольник]

Ну или просто бегунки, позволяющие выбрать величину отношения той или иной метке к конкретному вопросу. Причем, голосовать за отношение вопроса к меткам могли бы все участники, а не только его автор. С последующим агрегированием результатов, можно было бы организовывать довольно интересные сортировки. Но это так, мечты.. )

Отсутствие наследования в тегах - более чем нормально, т.к. фактически отношения между любыми метками очень относительны, и их просто нельзя сделать фиксированными.

Comment: Очень занятно. А как на счет отрицания меток? Если битрикс входит в PHP, то, подписавшись на PHP я подпишусь на битрикс. После этого убираю в настройках метку битрикс и в итоге не вижу вопросы, которые имеют связку  битрикс + PHP

Comment: Я дополнил предложение. почитайте UPD